# MVC 4 Server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am new to mvc in asp.net, so I have started with movie application in mvc with code first approach. My problem is when I change or add new field in movie class, then I got an error like

> The model backing the 'MovieDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

So anyone knows the solution for it with code first approach after changing or add any new field ...
using three command its solve which are list below.....which we have to write in package manager console

1)Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext

2)add-migration Initial

3)update-database

but why this error occurs and is there any other solution for it without the above three commands in mvc 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have changed the Code First models since applying them to your database, so you need to reupdate, to apply these changes. First you add a new migration. Do this by typying this into the package manager console:

```
add-migration migrationName
```

migrationName should be unique and descriptive of the changes. After running this command, you should have a migration file, which you can apply by running:

```
update-database
```

Given that the changes are valid, they should now be applied to your database.

You have to do this every time you make changes to your CF models.